# SET table variable from exec on stored procedure in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I don't believe this is possible, but want to confirm you cannot set a table variable from the results of executing a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008.

I was trying to do the following:

```
DECLARE @Results TABLE (RESULT_ID INT);

INSERT INTO @Results (RESULT_ID) VALUES (1);

SET @Results = 
EXEC dbo.[spResultLookup] @Results;
```

My goal is to pass `@Results` to the stored procedure and then to replace `@Results` with results from the call to `spResultLookup`.

The alternative is to delete the rows in `@Results` and use an `INSERT` with `EXEC` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a page from documentation that demonstrates how you can pass tables into procs but it definitely stipulates that you can't update the table with DML.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx

Of course you could create a temp table that would be available in scope to the caller and the proc. This is probably what you have to resort to for your use case.

```
CREATE table #tmp( id int, val VARCHAR(50))
go

CREATE PROC UpdateTmpTable as
begin
    insert into #tmp(id,val) values(1,'abc')
end
GO

exec dbo.UpdateTmpTable
select * from #tmp
```

Comment: Temp table is likely best option available. I was hoping for was a way to overwrite the calling table variable with the results of a call to stored procedure. Basically treating like other types like an INT or a VARCHAR.